# WSO2-EMM Problems Registering Windows Clients

Tags: wso2-iot

I've been having trouble getting Windows clients to register with the system.  I've added this to the SSL Reverse Proxy Server:

```
 ProxyPass /emm-web-agent http://172.16.1.82:9763/emm-web-agent
 ProxyPassReverse /emm-web-agent http://172.16.1.82:9763/emm-web-agent
```

Where 172.16.1.82 is the IP address of my MDM server.

In the Apache log's I'm seeing this:

```
172.16.1.149 - - [21/Jun/2016:16:35:02 -0500] "GET /EnrollmentServer/Discovery.svc HTTP/1.1" 200 3961 "-" "ENROLLClient"
172.16.1.149 - - [21/Jun/2016:16:35:02 -0500] "GET /EnrollmentServer/Discovery.svc HTTP/1.1" 200 181 "-" "ENROLLClient"
172.16.1.149 - - [21/Jun/2016:16:35:02 -0500] "POST /EnrollmentServer/Discovery.svc HTTP/1.1" 200 1578 "-" "ENROLLClient"
172.16.1.149 - - [21/Jun/2016:16:35:04 -0500] "GET /emm-web-agent/enrollments/windows/login-agent?appru=ms-app%3A%2F%2Fwindows.immersivecontrolpanel&login_hint=JeffR%40mydomain.com&username=JeffR%40mydomain.com HTTP/1.1" 302 4281 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; MSAuthHost/1.0/In-Domain; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
172.16.1.149 - - [21/Jun/2016:16:35:04 -0500] "GET /emm-web-agent/enrollments/error/unintentional-request HTTP/1.1" 302 389 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; MSAuthHost/1.0/In-Domain; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

Where 172.16.1.149 is the client computer.

I've tried various things, including rewriting the URL.  I'm not sure why it is giving the 302 error back from the emm-web-agent server.

Am I missing something in my configuration?  Thanks....

Comment: Could you able to provide the EMM version which you have tried?

Comment: Tried to enroll my windows 8.1 device on EMM 2.0.1. It was enrolled successfully. Could you able to provide the back-end error log.and also the response result for the POST /EnrollmentServer/Discovery.svc request? It would be helpful to resolve your issue.

Comment: I've been doing some more digging into the issue with not much luck.  I enabled dumpio on Apache and included a full trace [here at PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/tJ8GdwNr).  It appears to me that in the response XML, the AuthenticationServiceUrl is not correct.  It is showing https://EnterpriseEnrollment.hutchgov.com/emm-web-agent/enrollments/windows/login-agent, which isn't valid.  I've tried the ProxyPass redirect for the /emm-web-agent with no luck.

Comment: I wiped my installation and started over as a baseline.  It did make a difference.  I've left the emm-web-agent proxy settings in the Apache configurations.  Now I'm seeing this on the Windows clients:
Unintentional Request



Possible Causes :
[1] You have tried making a request call intended to be made by a different Platform. 
 [2] You have tried accessing enrollment steps out of order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be issue in your server certificate.The server SSL certificate must be domain specific.The wildcard SSL certificate (for
example, a certificate for *.hutchgov.com instead of enterpriseenrollment.hutchgov.com) is not accepted by the device.This Web authentication broker request(WAB) url is first https request which is coming from the device.If you can take a CA singed certificate for your domain(enterpriseenrollment.hutchgov.com),It would be resolved the issue.

Comment: Still not working.  I purchased a certificate from DigiCert, enrollmentserver.hutchgov.com.  I then installed it into the Apache2 reverse proxy.  I also wiped my installation and set it all up using the new name, enterrpiseenrollment.hutchgov.com.  I installed the certificate into the WSO2 .jks files.  I'm able to login to the management console and my browser is showing the correct certificate.  Yet the client is still saying: 
Unintentional Request
Possible Causes :
[1] You have tried making a request call intended to be made by a different Platform....

Comment: what was the certificate common name?

Comment: Enterpriseenrollment.hutchgov.com. I have it installed on both Apache and Tomcat.

Comment: If your common name is "Enterpriseenrollment.hutchgov.com",It should be fine. But I want to make sure that you have taken the certificate for enrollmentserver.hutchgov.com. According to your earlier comment."I purchased a certificate from DigiCert, enrollmentserver.hutchgov.com"

Comment: The certificate is installed on the servers and the browser are showing the correct certificate.  I'm not sure why we keep getting the "Unintended Request" message when it tries to bring up the login screen for device registration.

Comment: A bit of clarification after looking at some of the code.  I'm receiving this error message on a Windows 8.1 WORKSTATION and not a Windows Phone.  Does WSO2 support management of Windows Workstations like the Surface?

Comment: Wso2  EMM doesn't support Surface yet.

Comment: Are there any plans in future releases to support MDM on Windows 10?

Comment: We are planning to support Windows 10 which enable mobile device management (MDM) capabilities for PCs, laptops, tablets, and phones through a same management tool in a future release.

Comment: @JeffRoberson We are now reaching to  Wso2 IOT GA release, Windows 10 Device supporting feature is included there. here blog post related to the windows mdm flow http://hasuniea.blogspot.com/2017/01/windows-10-mdm-support-with-wso2-iot.html